# text field jquery auto-complete - only allow submissions within autocomplete options

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am looking for help in my code that allows an autocomplete, only within a specified data array. So only data within the auto complete array is allowed to be entered. Not sure where to do that .Here is my code. Can anyone suggest ??

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                         var data = ["ActionScript","AppleScript","Asp","BASIC","C","C++","iran","Scheme"];
                        $("#autocomplete").autocomplete(data);
                        });
    $('input#autocomplete').result(function (event, data, formatted) {
                        $("#result").html(!data ? "No match found!" : "Selected: " + formatted);
                    }).keyup(function () {
                       $(this).search();
                       $(this).css("background-color","#D6D6FF");                   
                    });

             } catch (e) { }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the `mustMatch` option ([docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete/autocomplete#url_or_dataoptions)):

```
$("#autocomplete").autocomplete(data, { mustMatch: true });
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/prCsm/

As a side note, this plugin has been deprecated in favor of the [jQueryUI version](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete).

Comment: Thank u for reply but if i done with mustMatch:true then in this case it also remove the valid data . for example if i wrote Asp01 then it remove full in textbox. see the following link and example no 3 http://mabp.kiev.ua/content/source/autocomplete/autocomplete.html, i want this type of behaviour that it dont allow to write anything after valid data. Any suggestion be appreciable : Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply disable the input field after the user selected a specific value. see line 6 in example code

example:

```
$("#autocomplete2").autocomplete({
  url:'search.php?type=xml',
  minchar:2,
  delay:1000, // in milliseconds
  onSelect:function(){
    $("#autocomplete2").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  },
  type:'xml'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I do the following:-

1. Set a flag to false when entering the field (onfocus)
2. Set the flag to true in the autocomplete select event
3. Test the flag in the field onblur event

If it is true the selection is good other wise it is bad and you can return focus to the input field.